# ctx.addEventListener makes canvas drawing disappear

Tags: javascript

When I add

```
 ctx.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown, false);
```

The canvas drawing (background and shapes) disappear and the page is blank, and then when I remove this event listener from the code they reappear again. Just wondering why this is happening? Thanks in advance

```
<script>


 var ctx, W, H;
 var x = 10;

window.onload = function() {


  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = W;
  canvas.height = H;


  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown, false); //When this is here, canvas drawing disappears, when it's not here canvas drawing reappears again




  setInterval(draw, 1);


function draw() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#E6E6FF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(x,20,10,10);
  ctx.font = "30px Arial";
  ctx.fillText("Hello World",10,80);
  ctx.fill();

}


}


function onDown(event) {
    //where x is found
    cx = event.pageX
    cy = event.pageY
    alert("X,Y ="+cx+','+cy);
}
```

Comment: Please check the console for error, note it will say `ctx.addEventListener is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add an event listener to the canvas's context.  You'll need to add it to the canvas itself.

Instead of:

```
ctx.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown, false);
```

… do this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onDown, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

***[jsBin demo](https://jsbin.com/coxomo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

use:

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener
```

or:

```
canvas.addEventListener
```

cause `context` is just an Object in which the HTMLElementCanvas lives in.

To spot such errors your-self, the easiest way is to debug your code using Developer Tools, opening the console tab and reading the errors you're shown:

[image]